# Double infinite sum: sum 1/(m^2 + n^2)^2, m=1..infinity, n=1..infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is this double infinite sum:
$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^2}$

I have search high and low without success.

Comment: Please edit your post to show your attempts. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).